# dockerのAlmalinux8コンテナの一般ユーザでcurlが失敗する

Tags: linux, docker, curl

### 問題

dockerのAlmalinux8コンテナの一般ユーザでcurlが失敗します。
rootユーザではcurlコマンドが成功するので、どこが悪さをしているのかがわかりません。
調査すべき点等あれば、ご教授頂きたいです。

```bash
[fuga@hoge ~]$ curl ipinfo.io
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ipinfo.io port 80: Connection timed out
```

```bash
[root@hoge /]# curl inet-ip.info
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

### マシンの概要

#### ホストOS

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
```

#### dockerのバージョン

```
docker --version
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
```

#### コンテナ上のOS

```
cat /etc/system-release
AlmaLinux release 8.7 (Stone Smilodon)
```

#### curlのバージョン

```
curl --version
curl 7.61.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.33.0
Release-Date: 2018-09-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

Comment: 可能なら `Dockerfile` も提示していただけると回答しやすくなりそうです / 質問文では `curl` 先のホストがrootと一般ユーザーで変えてありますが、これは意図があるのでしょうか？